# Making a converting program in python work with the latest version of python

Tags: python

A few years ago I found a conversion program on here for length and weight conversion. A friend of mine recently started a project where he needs this piece of code, but the project requires him to use the latest version of Python. I promised him I would help him as much as I could, but not having coded in python for years I can't really do much. I hope you guys can help. Whenever I run it I get the following two errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Tiberius\Documents\Konvertering.py", line 75, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\Tiberius\Documents\Konvertering.py", line 66, in main
s = raw_input("konverter hvad? (ex: 10 meter til fod) ")
NameError: global name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

The text is in danish btw. The code follows here:

```
units = {'kg':          ('vÃ¦gt', 1.),
'kilo':        ('vÃ¦gt', 1.),
'kilogram':    ('vÃ¦gt', 1.),
'lbs':          ('vÃ¦gt', 2.204),
'pund':       ('vÃ¦gt', 2.204),
'ton':       ('vÃ¦gt', 0.001),
'gram':        ('vÃ¦gt', 1000.),
'ounce':       ('vÃ¦gt', 35.27),
'm':           ('afstand', 1.),
'meter':       ('afstand', 1.),
'kilometer':   ('afstand', 0.001),
'km':          ('afstand', 0.001),
'centimeter':  ('afstand', 100.),
'cm':          ('afstand', 100.),
'meter':       ('afstand', 1.),
'mil':        ('afstand', 0.0006214),
'furlong':     ('afstand', 0.004971),
'league':      ('afstand', 0.0002071),
'fod':        ('afstand', 3.281),
'fod':        ('afstand', 3.281),
'tomme':        ('afstand', 39.37)}

def getUnit(unit_name):
    if unit_name in units:
        return units[unit_name]
    else:
        raise ValueError("ikke genkendt enhed '{0}'".format(unit_name))

def convert(amt, from_unit, to_unit):
    typeA, numA = getUnit(from_unit)
    typeB, numB = getUnit(to_unit)

if typeA==typeB:
    return amt * numB / numA
else:
    raise ValueError("enheder er af forskellige kategori ('{0}' and '{1}')".format(typeA, typeB))

def conversion(s):
    """
    Fortag enhedskonvertering

    Der accepteres en string i forment
    "(tal) (enhedA) [til] (enhedB)"

    Hvis enhed A og enhed B er af den samme type, vend tilbage med svaret .
    """
    s = s.strip().lower().split()
    if len(s) not in (3, 4):
        raise ValueError("Argument string har et forkert antal ord (skal vÃ¦re mellem tre eller fire)")
    try:
        amt = float(s[0])
    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError("argument string skal starte med et tal")
    from_unit = s[1]
    to_unit   = s[-1]
    return convert(amt, from_unit, to_unit)

def tryAgain():
    s = raw_input('prÃ¸v igen? (Y/n)? ').strip().lower()
    return 'yes'.startswith(s)

def main():
    while True:
        s = raw_input("konverter hvad? (ex: 10 meter til fod) ")
        try:
            print(": {0}".format(conversion(s)))
        except ValueError as v:
            print (v)
        if not tryAgain():
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: it looks like it is being converted from something `<=2.7.3` into `3x`, as they remove `raw_input`. Perhaps you could try using the `2to3` module that python has.

Answer (score 6):

`raw_input()` was renamed to `input()` in Python 3

Answer (score 3):

The `2to3` tool can help convert your Python 2 code into Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

First run 2to3 on it and then start fixing the remaining problems one by one.

Complete reference: http://python3porting.com/